# Problema con cin.getline

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Tengo un problema con la funcion getline, cuando voy a mostrar los datos, siempre me muestra menos de los que deberia haber, ya no se cual es el error
Si me pueden ayudar seria un gran favor

```
    void manejocadenas(void) {

    char cad[100]; char encript[100];

    for (int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
        cad[i]='\0';
        encript[i]='\0'; }
 cout<<"Recuerde que el limite establecido para la cadena a escribir es de 100"<<endl;
 system("pause");
 cout<<"Ingrese una cadena de texto"<<endl;
 cin>>cad;
 cin.getline(cad,100);
 cin.ignore();
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<endl; for (int x=0;x<=100;x++) { if (cad[x]!='\0') {

        encript[x]=cad[x]+3;
        cout<<encript[x]; } } cout<<endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunos cambios a tu codigo como que el for vaya hasta el tamaño de la cadena **cad** y elimine la linea de codigo en la que entrabas la cadena **cad** antes del getline... Esto lo probe y funiona me da una cadena del mismo tamaño que la de entrada que era el objetivo desde el principio. Espero que te ayude. Cualqier duda dejala en los comentarios

```
char cad[100];
char encript[100];

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    cad[i] = '\0';
    encript[i] = '\0';
}
cout << "Recuerde que el limite establecido para la cadena a escribir es de 100" << endl;
system("pause");
cout << "Ingrese una cadena de texto" << endl;
cin.getline(cad, 100);
cin.ignore();
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
for (int x = 0; x < strlen(cad); x++) {

        encript[x] = cad[x] + 3;
        cout << encript[x];

}
cout << endl;
```